# 2 Select Boxes - Select Box 1 (A,B,C...) fills Select Box 2, doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to have the output in select box 2 in such a way that if I choose something with B in select box 1, everything that begins with B in select box 1 is output. At the moment only one is issued and the others are not

```js
$('#select1').on('change', () => {
  $('#select2 option').hide();
  $('#select2 option[value^="' + $('#select1').val() + '" ]').show();
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="standard" size="1" id="select1">
  <option value="0">A</option>
  <option value="1">B</option>
  <option value="2">C</option>
  <option value="3">D</option>
  <option value="4">E</option>
  <option value="5">F</option>
  <option value="6">G</option>
  <option value="7">H</option>
  <option value="8">I</option>
  <option value="9">J</option>
  <option value="10">K</option>
  <option value="11">L</option>
  <option value="12">M</option>
</select>

<select name="standard" size="1" id="select2">
  <option value="0" style="">Aal in Aspik</option>
  <option value="1" style="display: none;">Bierwurst</option>
  <option value="2" style="display: none;">Berliner (Faschingskrapfen)</option>
  <option value="3" style="display: none;">Auberginenröllchen auf Tomaten-Zimt-Sugo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Answer (score 0):

Since your selector `#select2 option[value^="' + $('#select1').val() + '" ]` will only match one options, so the other options that have greater value still not be showed. You could try to use jQuery's [filter](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$('#select1').on('change', () => {
  var value1 =  $('#select1').val();
  var option2 = $('#select2 option');
  $('#select2').val(value1).change();
  option2.hide();
  option2.filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).val()) >= parseInt(value1);
  }).show();
}).trigger('change');
```

See demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h569ezo2/)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
[value^="' + $('#select1').val() + '" ]
```

If you debug select val, you'll see it's `1` for `B` as it takes the option `value`:

```
<option value="1">B</option>
```

To compare texts, you need to get the text of the current selected option, eg:

```
$('#select1 option:selected').text()
```

you can then use `.filter` to compare this with the first letter of each option in the second select:

```
$('#select2 option').filter((i,e)=> $(e).text().substr(0,1) == $('#select1 option:selected').text()).show();
```

Updated snippet:

```js
$('#select1').on('change', () => {
  $('#select2 option').hide();
  $('#select2 option').filter((i,e)=> $(e).text().substr(0,1) == $('#select1 option:selected').text()).show();
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="standard" size="1" id="select1">
  <option value="0">A</option>
  <option value="1">B</option>
  <option value="2">C</option>
  <option value="3">D</option>
  <option value="4">E</option>
  <option value="5">F</option>
  <option value="6">G</option>
  <option value="7">H</option>
  <option value="8">I</option>
  <option value="9">J</option>
  <option value="10">K</option>
  <option value="11">L</option>
  <option value="12">M</option>
</select>

<select name="standard" size="1" id="select2">
  <option value="0" style="">Aal in Aspik</option>
  <option value="1" style="display: none;">Bierwurst</option>
  <option value="2" style="display: none;">Berliner (Faschingskrapfen)</option>
  <option value="3" style="display: none;">Auberginenröllchen auf Tomaten-Zimt-Sugo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: They could also change the values in the first select to be the letters instead of numbers.

Comment: @Barmar yes. That would also still require a change to .filter to match letter.  Another alternative would be to add a data-parentvalue to the 2nd and match 1st value to 2nd data-parentvalue.   Care needs to be taken when suggesting value changes as it may be used "upstream" eg see [this question's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75436982/why-is-my-cascading-dropdown-list-using-json-is-not-returning-the-item-selected)